# Data Manipulation / Analysis / Aggregation using EXCEL instead of R or SQL -- Composite Key of 2 columns, calculated sum of counts

Tags: sql-server, excel, aggregate, composite-key

I asked around and still no solution.  People just told me "easy with PivotTable", but said easier than done, and no solution so far.

I would like to use Excel 2013/2016 to do the following:

**1. Raw Data**

I have a **comma separated** text file like this, with 2.8 million rows:

**Table 1:**

```
Cell_Id, Gene_Id, Count
gcatatgc,AAK1,36
gcatatgc,ABHD14B,5
gcatatgc,ABHD17B,20
tttggcca,ABI3,4
tttggcca,AAK1,50
tttggcca,ABHD14B,6
aaaggctt,ABT1,5
aaaggctt,ACAA1,14
aaaggctt,AAK1,50
aaaggctt,ABHD14B,6
ggaggcaa,AAK1,50
ggaggcaa,ABHD14B,6
ggaggcaa,AAK1,36
ggaggcaa,ABHD14B,5
......
....
```

The `Cell_ID` and `Gene_ID` have duplicates.

**2. Step A**. from above CSV text file, I want to create a table, of distinct `Cell_ID` and generate new column with unique key number of each distinct `Cell_ID`.

**generated Table 2:**

```
Distinct_Cell_ID, Key_Distinct_Cell_ID
gcatatgc, 1
tttggcca, 2
aaaggctt, 3 
ggaggcaa, 4
......
....
```

**3. Step B**, also create another table, of distinct Gene_ID and generate new column with unique key number of each distinct Gene_ID.

**generated Table 3:**

```
Distinct_Gene_ID, Key_Distinct_Gene_ID
AAK1,1
ABHD14B,2
ABHD17B,3
ABI3,4
ABT1,5
ACAA1,6
......
....
```

**4. Step C**, generate a new table, from Table 1, 2 and 3, group by `Distinct_Cell_ID` and `Distinct_Gene_ID`, and generate a group count sum, grouped by `(Distinct_Cell_ID`, `Distinct_Gene_ID`) unique pairs.

**generated Table 4:**

```
Key_Distinct_Cell_ID, Key_Distinct_Gene_ID, Sum_Group_Count
1, 1, 36
1, 2, 5
1, 3, 20
2, 4, 4
2, 1, 50
2, 3, 6
3, 5, 50
3, 6, 6
3, 1, 36
3, 2, 5
......
....
```

and output this Table 4 to a Comma Separated CSV file.

**5. Step D**, generate 3 "Total Values"

```
Total count of Distinct_Cell_ID's, 
Total count of Distinct_Gene_ID's, 
Total sum of count in Table 1.
```

I would appreciate if someone can help, to show me how to do steps A, B, C and D in EXCEL 2013 or EXCEL 2016.

- need to extract "distinct" values (remove duplicates) from one column to another column, and then generate a serial-key number next to new column, for both column Cell_ID (new columns Distinct_Cell_ID and Key_Distinct_Cell_ID) and column Gene_ID (new columns Distinct_Gene_ID and Key_Gene_Cell_ID).
- Create another table with columns Key_Distinct_Gene_ID, Key_Distinct_Cell_ID, and generate a 3rd column of the sum of "Count"s, looking up raw data table 1, with combined-key of (Distinct_Gene_ID,  Distinct_Cell_ID) == (Gene_ID,  Cell_ID)
- Also the table 1 to 4 and the values in step D, **can be refreshed** when the source CSV file changes, perhaps by one click of an EXCEL feature button.

(Although it look like easier to do it by R/Python program or SQL Server, but I wonder how to do this in Excel).

I have written a R Markdown script to this this, but still cannot figure out how to do it in EXCEL.

Said is easier than done.

I hope this question is specific enough for someone to answer.

Regards
Alex

Comment: What specifically did you already try, and what problems did you run into? You could try approaches such as running a SQL query to get the distinct combinations and counts, or if you're familiar with VBA you could try (eg) using dictionaries to extract unique values and create key values.  It doesn't sound like you really *need* a solution in Excel though...

Comment: My son was working in the lab of School of Life Sciences, and he had this task of data analysis on some research, given by his professor.   I attended the edX Microsoft course of "Data Analysis and Visualization with EXCEL".  Thus my first reaction was "EXCEL with PowerPivot".   Then I tried but failed to find out the steps/tools in EXCEL to achieve this.  My son laughed at me, saying that EXCEL was not up to such simple data analysis-processing task.  I asked the same question in Microsoft EXCEL forum, and have not got back any answer yet.   So I wonder if EXCEL can really do this or not.

Comment: The main problem with doing it **in** Excel is the 2.8M rows in the source file: you could do it *from* Excel using VBA and the ADO text driver, but that's not really using any of the Excel functionality.  I'm not familiar with PowerPivot

Comment: Hi Tim,

Suppose it is 2800 rows only.  I wonder it can be done using EXCEL, may not be fully automated; can be with a few clicks.   Should not need to write VBA/ADO programs though, I think.

Comment: With 2800 rows a pivot table would be a good place to start.